# Strange UDP issue on Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, sockets, udp

I'm experiencing a very strange issue on Windows 10. Sending from one UDP socket to another, both on the same local network interface, doesn't work.

- Sending to the same UDP socket works as expected
- Sending to/from another machine works as expected
- If I'm using the loopback interface (127.0.0.1), it works as expected
- I tried several interfaces (sending from an interface to itself), and even different addresses on the same interface - nothing seems to work.
- This works as expected on Windows 7 and on Linux.
- Port binding succeeds.

It worked fine until a few days ago, and I have no idea what broke it.

The following ruby script demonstrates the problem:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'socket'

addr = IPSocket.getaddress(Socket.gethostname)
u1 = UDPSocket.new
u1.bind(addr, 5010)
u2 = UDPSocket.new
u2.bind(addr, 5020)
u1.send('abcd', 0, addr, 5010)
p u1.recvfrom(4) # Works
u1.send('abcd', 0, addr, 5020)
p u2.recvfrom(4) # Fails
```

Comment: Why was it migrated? This is a networking issue, not a programming issue.

Comment: "It worked fine until a few days ago, and I have no idea what broke it." Yes, sigh. This is my main experience when working with Windows.

Answer (score 0):

One thing which can make the code above fail is if there is something else listening for UDP packets on port 5020 on this machine and this other UDP receiver absorbs your packet and `u2` never receives it.

But my next thought would be that then your `bind()` should fail in the first place, but there are socket options to not make it fail and to allow multiple servers listening on the same port. In this case it is random which socket receives which packet. This might explain what you see.

I must admit I am not sure what the exact semantics of `bind()` are for Windows 10, and what the exact behavior is when multiple UDP servers listen on the same port (and whether this is possible on Windows 10 at all).

The typical 'Windows' semantics for bind() are: When bound to a non-zero IP address, bind to the network interface this IP address belongs to. (While on Linux it means: Filter all incoming packets for a destination address of that non-zero IP address while binding to *all* network interfaces.)

Comment: Not your fault. Microsoft have completely failed to define the semantics of multiple proceses listening to or receving at the same port. How it is supposed to work is anybody's guess. Moral: don't.

Comment: Thanks, but that's definitely not the problem. The port is not used by any other application (if I try with a used port, bind raises an exception), and it doesn't matter which port I choose - always the same result. I also tried binding only one of the sockets, and sending from the other one - doesn't work.

Comment: Argh. Igt would have been too easy, wouldn't it. What does "route print" say for the IP address you selected? I must admit I am not sure it will print anything about the local routing. On Linux local routing is far from trivial and uses its own routing table (see "ip route show table local"). I do not know what the Windows equivalent is. I realize I have more questions than answers ...